# Can i double tap a particular part of my screen to make something happen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, position, touch, destroy

I am trying to make a powerup for my unity game where if the player double taps the screen, the monsters would disappear but i want the second tap on the screen to be in the same position as the first for the monster to be deleted. How do i go about this?

```
void Update()
{   
    if (transform.position.y < -15f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    bool doubleTapD = false;

    #region doubleTapD

    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; ++i)
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            if (Time.time < _doubleTapTimeD + .3f)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
                doubleTapD = true;
            }
        }

        _doubleTapTimeD = Time.time;
    } 

    #endregion

    if (doubleTapD)
    {
        Debug.Log("DoubleTapD");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Can i double tap a particular part of my screen to make something happen` -> Yes of course .... could you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like actually you want to track not any touch but rather touches on the monster object itself.

Therefore I would actually rather recommend using [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html) which is also triggered by touches but is only triggered, if the mouse down / touch actually happens on top of the according collider.

So I would write your code as e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private float doubleTapDelay = 0.3f;

// store a flag whether the first tap was already handled
private bool firstTap;
// store the last time a first tap was handled
private float lastTap;

private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(!firstTap)
    {
        // this is a first tap -> only set the flag and store he time
        lastTap = Time.time;
        firstTap = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // this is a second tap!
        OnDoubleTap();
        // reset the flag just in case
        firstTap = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{   
    if (transform.position.y < -15f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // if the time has exceeded doubleTapDelay since the last tap, reset the flag
    if(Time.time >= lastTap + doubleTapDelay)
    {
        firstTap = false;
    }
}

private void OnDoubleTap()
{
    Debug.Log("Was double tapped!");
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Now your user as to double tap actually on the monster itself and not just anywhere on the screen.

---

Otherwise if you actually want to be able to tap anywhere on the screen but twice at more or less the same screen position you could do something quite similar but have to define a range (in pixels!) like e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private float doubleTapDelay = 0.3f;
// additionally define a range within which the second touch is valid
[SerializeField] private float rangeInPixels = 30;

// store a flag whether the first tap was already handled
private bool firstTap;
// store the last time a first tap was handled
private float lastTap;
// additionally store the first touch position
private Vector2 firstTouchPoint;

void Update()
{   
    if (transform.position.y < -15f)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    // rather use this instead of GetTouch as it is quite slow
    foreach (var touch in Input.touches)
    {
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            if(!firstTap)
            {
                lastTap = Time.time;
                firstTap = true;
                firstTouchPoint = touch.position;
            }
            else
            {
                // check if the second touch is within the range around the first touch
                if(Vector2.Distance(firstTouchPoint, touch.position) <= rangeInPixels)
                {
                    OnDoubleTap();
                }
                
                firstTap = false;
            }

            // you probably want to make sure only one tap is handled per frame
            // otherwise it would count as double tap if a user simply taps with two fingers at the same time ;)
            break;
        }
    }

    if(Time.time >= lastTap + doubleTapDelay)
    {
        firstTap = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to capture a double-tap, wherever it is on screen. You can achieve this using the new InputSystem and let it do the hard work.

Create an action map. Within it create an action. For the binding, select a touch or mouse click. Finally add a Multi-tap interaction and set the parameters for timing and distance there.

[image: Screenshot of InputSystem input action map showing touch (tap) binding with multi tap interaction]

[image: Screenshot of InputSystem input action map showing left mouse binding with multi tap interaction]

There are many (video) tutorials showing how to get started with the InputSystem.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a very similar situation as yours. In my case I wanted to ZoomIn on a particular Item ONLY when the two consecutive taps were sufficiently close (position wise.) The Solution below worked for me with the New Input System.

[image]
[image]
[image]

And the concomitant code:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class DoubleTapBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {
private TouchInputActionA controls;
private Vector2 firstTapLocation;
private float allowedSecondTapDistance = 40;
private void Awake() => controls = new TouchInputActionA();
private void OnEnable() {
    controls.Enable();
    controls.Item.ZoomIn.started += ctx => FirstTapofTwo();
    controls.Item.ZoomIn.performed += ctx => DoubleTap();
}
private void OnDisable() {
    controls.Disable();
    controls.Item.ZoomIn.started -= ctx => FirstTapofTwo();
    controls.Item.ZoomIn.performed -= ctx => DoubleTap();
}
private void FirstTapofTwo(){
    // Get the location of your first tap. 
    firstTapLocation = controls.Item.Coordinate.ReadValue<Vector2>();
}
private void DoubleTap() {
    Vector2 secondTapLocation=controls.Item.Coordinate.ReadValue<Vector2();
    float distance = Vector2.Distance(secondTapLocation, firstTapLocation);
    if(distance<allowedSecondTapDistance) {
       Debug.Log("SecondTap within Firstap range: Monster disappear!");
    }
}    
}
```

The crux of the solution is the additional "Coordinate" Action which allows you to store the position of the first tap when the ZoomIn Action is started. Adjust the value of allowedSecondTapDistance accordingly. Note the Pass-Through Action-Type on the Coordinate Action. I found the Value Action-Type to sometimes give a position of (0,0) for the first tap irrespective of where I tapped.